# How to build a module base application using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, mef, maf

I am trying to build a large application using ASP.NET MVC and entity frameworks. I know this project will become very large at some point so I want to make sure I design it in a way to be able to manage it without lots of unnecessary work specially when I have more programmers helping me down the road.

Another thing I like to consider is the application deployment. I don't want to have to keep compiling my application every time I make update or add new section to my application.

I believe using the MVC design will keep my code clean and easier to maintain. But one thing I really want to enforce is a module design to keep my files organized.

Based on some searching I have done, three things came up Areas, MEF and MAF which seems to be based off the same idea.

I also learned that MAF may be an over kill for most projects where MEF is more in the lines of what I may be looking for.

Most of the articles that I found are at least 2 years old and talks about ASP.NET MVC 4. I am not sure how relevant that is to ASP.NET MVC 5 or ASP.NET MVC 6.

What is confusing to me is that MEF is a framework and ASP.NET MVC is another framework. Is it possible to use the two frameworks to get an MVC design with module base application that allows me to organize my file and not to have to compile my application every time I need to make an update or add a new module?

Is the combination of MVC and MEF consider a good start for a large application? Is there a better idea that I should consider when designing my application?

Comment: This is way too broad/opinion based for SO... Note on 5 vs. Core - the frameworks are different enough so advises about one may not be applicable to another. For 5 articles that are 2 years old are definitely applicable...

Comment: `I don't want to have to keep compiling my application every time I make update or add new section to my application.` - Using continuous integration/continuous deployment in conjunction with [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) makes this relatively simple to achieve. Don't make a design more complicated than you need just for the sake of deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think MEF is the answer to what you're looking for. MEF was designed with the idea of giving to the developers the ability to create a "pluggable" architecture.

Imagine to develop an app whose core will be shared among different clients, but with some custom modules for some of them. Then MEF is what you're looking for.

Instead, from what you're saying, I think you're just trying to create a tidy and solid architecture, easy to maintain in the future. You don't need MEF for that.

Here is a good article about how to structure big MVC applications keeping in mind the principle of separation of concerns: https://chsakell.com/2015/02/15/asp-net-mvc-solution-architecture-best-practices/

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the article well. But It does not seems to be using the ASP.NET MVC framework. I think I want to stick with ASP.net MVC but like to separate my files into different folders

Comment: Of course it uses MVC. It just basically tells you to create a separate project for your services, data access, domain and mvc application